# Adding up multiple years debits vs credits

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have multiple Year columns (debits vs credits ) that I add up in an aggregate view. I want to add credits to one field and debits to another. Tried SUMIFS and can't get it to fly. Any help greatly appreciated.